# How to EncodeToPng compressed Textures in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I develop an app that saves textures (screenshots) and I need to compress them, but then- I can't use `EncodeToPNG` method in order to show the image on the screen.

My steps:

1. `Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(recwidth, recheight,
   TextureFormat.RGB24, false);` //RGB24- Because of the next step:
2. `tex.ReadPixels(rex, rdPXX, rdPXY); 
   tex.Apply();`
3. `tex.Compress(false);`

Later I need to show it on the screen with-

4. `var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();`

But I can't because as we all know `EncodeToPNG` doesn't support compressed textures, so what can I do? It takes a lot of space on my mobile

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/787616/save-compressed-texture-as-png.html

Comment: Since you're developing an app, remember that .Compress will only work if the hardware supports .DXT, which is not the case of most mobile devices.

Comment: Sani- I saw that post on answers.unity, but it still gives me issues after doing that. Nathalie, thanks that's true, but I'm having the same problem when compressing to ASTC which is supported by mobile

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to decompress the Texture first before using `EncodeToPNG` on it. You should be able to do this with `RenderTexture`. Copy the compressed `Texture2D` to `RenderTexture`. Assign the `RenderTexture` to `RenderTexture.active` then use `ReadPixels` to copy the pixels from the `RenderTexture` to the new `Texture2D` you wish to be in decompressed format. Now, you can use `EncodeToPNG` on it.

The helper function to do this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static Texture2D DeCompress(this Texture2D source)
    {
        RenderTexture renderTex = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(
                    source.width,
                    source.height,
                    0,
                    RenderTextureFormat.Default,
                    RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);

        Graphics.Blit(source, renderTex);
        RenderTexture previous = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = renderTex;
        Texture2D readableText = new Texture2D(source.width, source.height);
        readableText.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTex.width, renderTex.height), 0, 0);
        readableText.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = previous;
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTex);
        return readableText;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Create a compressed Texture:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(recwidth, recheight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
tex.ReadPixels(rex, rdPXX, rdPXY);
tex.Apply();
tex.Compress(false);
```

Create a new decompressed Texture from the compressed Texture:

```
Texture2D decopmpresseTex = tex.DeCompress();
```

Encoded to png

```
var bytes = decopmpresseTex.EncodeToPNG();
```

Comment: As a note: If you are using a different pixelPerUnit on your images you should set it on sprite creation phase. Like that:

Sprite.Create(loadedTexture, new Rect(0f, 0f, loadedTexture.width, loadedTexture.height), new Vector2(.5f,.5f), 2048);

 //2048 is example pixelPerUnit
If you don't do this you will only see some pixels and think about "what's wrong" just like me :)